# Formula for Arclength of Geodesic Connecting Two Points in the Surface of a Cylinder

Tags: geometry

Given two points laying on the surface of a cylinder, is there a simple equation for the arclength of the geodesic that connects those two points?

In my use case, the cylinder is oriented axially coincident with the x axis.  I have two points for which I know their (x,y,z) locations, and I understand that I can convert these coordinates to cylindrical coordinates by the transformation x=x, y=rcos(theta), z=rsin(theta).  Beyond that, I am not sure is there is a simple equation for calculating the geodesic length of between these two points without "unrolling" the cylinder into a plane and using the distance formula.

Can someone confirm for me if it is simply: L=SQRT(r^2θ^2+x^2), where x ix the axial distance which separates the points in my example?  Is it this easy?

Thank you.

Comment: Peel the skin off the the cylinder and unroll it.  Now you have a rectangle. So yes, the square root of the sum of the squares  of the shorter lateral distance and vertical distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geodesic of cylinders are known to be

- 1) either **helixical arcs** (the shortest helixical arc connecting the two points).
- 2) or vertical segments

Let us consider case 1). When the cylinder, as a **ruled** surface is unrolled **isometrically** :

- the ordinates of the points stay the same, whereas
- abscissas are measured by the unrolling of arc lengthes $r \theta$.

The geodesic (piece of an helix) is mapped isometrically onto the geodesic of the plane which is the line segment connecting points $(x_1=r \theta_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2=r \theta_2,y_2)$.

Its arc length is thus :

$$\sqrt{(r(\theta_2-\theta_1))^2+(y_2-y_1)^2} \tag{1}$$

(almost as you, @user1998586, gave it ; why didn't you modify your  answer instead of erasing it ?).

In the exceptional case where the geodesic is a vertical segment (corresponding to the case where the two points are on a same vertical line), happily, the isometrical mapping works the same : formula (1) is still valid with $\theta_2=\theta_1$ under the simplified form $$|y_1-y_2|$$

Comment: Thank you @Jean Marie, this looks like exactly what I need.  Two questions:  in your equation (1), should the "r" term be squared?  Additionally, how do I modify this equation to fit my stipulation that the cylinder is oriented along the x-axis?

Comment: Question 1) Yes, the r term has to be squared (I correct it at once).

Comment: Question 2) : what do you mean exactly by "oriented along the x-axis" ?

Comment: Maybe you mean that the first point has coordinates $(x=0,y=r)$ meaning you start with a $\theta=\pi/2$ angle, then you proceed in a clockwise manner to point $(x=r,y=0)$ reaching $\theta=0$ ?

Comment: Hi Jean Marie, thank you for the equation correction.  What I mean is, the axis of the cylinder is coincident with the x-axis, in my question.  Therefore, a cylindrical coordinate on my cylinder would be (r, theta, x), not (r, theta, z).

Comment: This doesn't change the formula : the unrolling will take place on a horizontal plane, the $x$ cordinate will be preserved and the $r$ and $\theta$ coordinates will be gathered as a single coordinate $r \theta$ ; thus formula (1) will be : $\sqrt{(r(\theta_2-\theta_1))^2+(x_2-x_1)^2}$.

Comment: Thank you kindly Jean Marie

Comment: @JeanMarie the reason I deleted my original answer was because on re-reading the question, I interpreted the wording 'without "unrolling" the cylinder' in the question to be asking for a formula using Euclidean not polar co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You can "hide" the unrolling by using trig functions to convert chord-length to arc length.

A chord of length $l$ on a circle of radius $r$ gives an arc-length of $2 r \arcsin \frac{l}{2r}$

Given points on the cylinder with $\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$, $\Delta y = y_2 - y_1$, $\Delta z = z_2 - z_1$ we then get the geodesic length:
$$
\sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + 4r^2 \arcsin^2 \left(\frac{1}{2r}\sqrt{(\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta z)^2}\right)}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It seems like there must be a more concise equation if we were to convert the Cartesian coordinates to cylindrical coordinates, and fix r to a constant such that the two points lie on the coordinate surface r=C, and the two points are then only defined by their theta and x coordinate.  Is this logic reasonable?